# User's history and pagination with Deezer APIs

Tags: api, deezer

if I try to get the streaming history of a user, e.g.

```
http://api.deezer.com/2.0/user/.../history?access_token=...
```

I get the first result page but I don't see any method/parameter (like next, page, ...) to see the rest of the results.

How can I get the following result pages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parameters available to control the paging of data:

- limit: the number of individual track objects that are returned in the request.
- index: the individual track objects at the specified index that is the first result of the request to be returned.

Please, compare these two requests to get a better understanding of the paging system:

- http://api.deezer.com/user/YOUR_USER_ID/history?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN&index=0&limit=10 will return the 10 latest tracks you listened to.
- http://api.deezer.com/user/YOUR_USER_ID/history?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN&index=4&limit=5 will return the 5 tracks before the 5 latest tracks you listened to.

For your information, you cannot return more than 50 individual objects per page.

Comment: Thanks it works. I guess there is no way to know the total number of pages, so if I want to retrieve the whole history I have to go on 50 by 50 until a page having no results is returned?

Comment: Exactly.
Due to the caching of the user history you won't get the total for now.
Also, you indeed receive two properties in the Json file called 'next' and 'previous'. That will be a simple string containing the URL of the request for getting to next or previous 50 tracks such as "http://api.deezer.com/user/me/history?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN&index=50&limit=50".

Comment: There is NO next property and that was the reason why I posted this question; I have just tried again with my user, no NEXT no previous. Try yourself.