# How do I get the complete track history of a Deezer user?

Tags: deezer

I want to analyse my music consumption on Deezer.
Researching resulted in their [rest api](https://developers.deezer.com/api) but the amount of entries in the user history seems to be limited (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19497151/9909548 to navigate through all entries).
In my case, it resulted in only about 140 tracks which should be thousands.
From now on I could regularly store the results of that request but all data till now would be lost.
I'm aware that, by EU law, I could request all stored user data and parse that (in case I get it digitally) but I would not consider that a solution.

Is there a different api call to get the complete history or another api or some other way to get this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to access the entire history:

> Deezer Support on 05.12.2020

> Hello, Thanks for your email, apologies for the delay in getting back to you. XXX from Support here
> https://www.deezer.com/app/stateeztics/
> that is the best tool,  but else sadly we do not have data analysis tools or data, besides recently played. Other option though: 2020 highlights (in Music)
> Kind regards, XXX

The recommended app is stuck when opened and Deezer is slowly stopping their support for app extensions anyway.